# Can we pass Map<sobject,list<sobject>> mspsaa as the parameter in batch class execute method?

Tags: apex, batch

**/* Before deleting the account records, i want to fetch its associated contacts and reparent them to other account and then delete the actual account records. */**

```
global class Deletebulkaccountsample implements database.Batchable <sobject>
{

      list<contact> lstcon = new list<contact>();
      list<account> lstact = new list<account>();
      map<Account,list<contact>> mapacccon = new map<account,list<contact>>(); 
global database.querylocator start(database.BatchableContext bcon)

{
    return database.getQueryLocator([select id, (select id,accountid from contacts) from account where name like 'ADP Limited']);

}

   global void execute(database.BatchableContext bcon,map<sobject,list<sobject>> lstsoj)

   {
       system.debug(lstsoj.size());      
       mapacccon = (map<account,list<contact>>)lstsoj;

       for(contact con : mapacccon.values())
            {
                    con.accountid = '00128000010UjnR' ;

                     lstcon.add(con);

                           }

                           update lstcon;
                          delete [select id from account where name like 'ADP Limited'];

                   }

    global void finish(database.BatchableContext bcon)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: global void execute(database.BatchableContext bcon,map<sobject,list<sobject>> lstsoj)

Comment: Iam facing the below error:

Class Deletebulkaccountsample must implement the method: void Database.Batchable<SObject>.execute(Database.BatchableContext, List<SObject>)

Comment: Don't ever use SObject map keys. It's just a bad idea. Use the Id instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question literally, yes, but you'd have to change your start method:

```
global List<Map<SObject,List<SObject>>> start(database.BatchableContext bcon)
{
   /* build a List<Map<SObject,List<SObject>>> here */
}
```

And your class' interface:

```
global class Deletebulkaccountsample implements database.Batchable<Map<SObject, List<SObject>>>
```

However, that's almost never what you'd want to do. Instead, you just pass in a normal list:

```
global void execute(database.BatchableContext bcon, Account[] lstsoj)
  for(Account accountRecord: lstsoj) {
    for(Contact contactRecord: accountRecord.Contacts) {
      // Do stuff here
    }
  }
  // etc...
}
```

---

*However*, **do not do this**.

---

There are some **serious** performance implications when returning child or parent records in the start method. *Consider yourself warned*. Instead, query just the initial records first:

```
global database.querylocator start(database.BatchableContext bcon)
{
    return database.getQueryLocator([select id from account where name like 'ADP Limited']);
}
```

And then, in your execute method, query the children:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
  Account[] records = [SELECT (SELECT AccountId FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id = :scope];
  // More stuff here...
}
```

The reason why is that serializing all the children causes a massive processing penalty on the initial query, and in fact, you might even time out if it takes too long. Doing it this way keeps your batch running at optimal speed.

Comment: i think we can use the below code aswell. Correct me if iam diverting..

Comment: @santoshkumar Again, you *can* do it, but I advise against it.

Answer (score 0):

```
global class deletebulkaccountbatch implements database.Batchable<sobject>
{

      list<contact> lstcon = new list<contact>();
      list<account> lstact = new list<account>();

global database.querylocator start(database.BatchableContext bcon)

{
    return database.getQueryLocator([select id, (select id,accountid from contacts) from account where name like 'ADP Limited']);

}

   global void execute(database.BatchableContext bcon,list<sobject> lstsoj)

   {
       system.debug(lstsoj.size());  

// Typecasting list of sobject records to list of account records.

       list<Account> lss = (list<account>)lstsoj;

             for(account acc : lss)
              {
                   for(contact con : acc.contacts)

                          {
                                   con.accountid = '00128000010UjnR' ;

                                   lstcon.add(con);

                           }

                           update lstcon;

                }
                       delete [select id from account where name like 'ADP Limited'];

       }

    global void finish(database.BatchableContext bcon)
    {

    }
}
```